# Understanding Typescript,Angular arrow function

Tags: angular, typescript

I am very new to angular . I didn't understand some snippet of code although i tried a lot.
Can anyone explain how below 3 functions works along with input,output and body.

```
private _rowClass: (row: T) => {[key: string]: boolean} = _ => {return {};};

  @Input() public set rowClass(func: (row: T) => {[key: string]: boolean}) {
    this._rowClass = func;
  }

  public get rowClass(): (row: T) => {[key: string]: boolean} {
    if (this.condition) {
      return _ => {return {};};
    }
    return this._rowClass;
  }

    @Input()
    public set rows(value: T[]) {
        this._rows = value
       }
```

In the template

```
  <ngx-datatable
    [rowClass]="rowClass"
    [rows]="rows"
     >
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question a bit more? Maybe post the full class code or explain where that code comes from

Comment: @MassimilianoSartoretto Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

At first I have to say that this code is really ugly and against any clean code rules.

TL;DR: [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are function expressions which are helpful to keep the `this` scope from the parent. But here they are used because you have to prefer arrow function in modern JavaScript / TypeScript.

`private _rowClass: (row: T) => {[key: string]: boolean} = _ => {return {};};`

This line defines a method which uses the variablen name `_` as argument. The variable `_rowClass` is now a function `_ => {return {}}`
which is equal to `function (_) {return {};}`. Alert: The variable name `_` is not good. Use a-zA-Z0-9 for variable names. btw. the argument `_` is not used and can be removed.

Note that the code after `:` of e.g. `_rowClass: <THIS>` is just the type from TypeScript. The type is `(row: T) => {[key: string]: boolean}` Which means that it's a method with generic type argument `row: T` (T any type you pass) and the returned value of it an object with any property key which have boolean as value. `[key: string]: boolean`

`public get rowClass(): (row: T) => {[key: string]: boolean} {`

This is only the getter `get` with the same type definition to return the `_rowClass` or in this case if `this.condition` is true, it returns a new instance of the method `_ => {return {}}`.

Here is a simplified version in JavaScript. I removed the complex TypeScript types to keep it clean. Just to demonstrate here.

```js
class YourClass {
  // A private member accessible via setter and getter below.
  // The value is a function (which is also a class in ES5. Constructor function).
  _rowClass = function() {
    return {};
  };

  // The setter of the private property above.
  set rowClass(func) {
    this._rowClass = func;
  }

  // The getter of the private property above.
  // Returns a new constructor function if the property "condition" of this class is true.
  get rowClass() {
    if (this.condition) {
      return function() {
        return {};
      };
    }
    return this._rowClass;
  }

  // Just a method to set the private property _rows.
  set rows(value) {
    this._rows = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Now,if i want to call rowClass() what should i pass as argument ? 
Like this this.rowClass({'sd':true})  @Dominik